# How can I insert a formula into another sheet referring to a cell in the Active Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called *Line Item Summary* with cell E7 that has the formula `='Costing Sheet'!I75`. Instead of having the formula reference *Costing Sheet* I would like to replace it with the sheet that is being worked on (so the active sheet) .

The active sheet name may change as copies are made but the cell I75 where there data is referencing will always be the same.

I have tried the following code but I get "Run-time error '9':Subscript out of range".

```
Sub Connect()

Sheets("Line Item Summary").Range("E7").Formula = "='ActiveSheet'!I75"

End Sub
```

I tried to explain this as best I can but please let me know if it needs clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `activesheet` from the quotes otherwise it is treated as a literal string.

```
Sub Connect()

Sheets("Line Item Summary").Range("E7").Formula = "='" & ActiveSheet.name & "'!I75"

End Sub
```

But your formula will change - is that what you intend?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried this with your changes but still got the same error. In essence, I would like cell E7 of _Line Item Summary_ to equal cell I75 of the active sheet.

Comment: Silly mistake, I spelled the Line Item Summary sheet wrong! Thank you for your help

Comment: @icalderon you should still properly qualify any `Sheets`/`Worksheets` calls with a `Workbook` object, and any `Range`/`Cells`/`Columns`/`Rows`/`Names` calls with a proper `Worksheet` object.